# Mac застрял на установщике windows

Tags: windows, mac

При установке windows с помощью bootcamp на Mac возникла проблема «Установка windows на данный диск невозможна. Возможно, оборудование данного компьютера не поддерживает загрузку с данного диска». Вопрос, как мне теперь выйти из установщика и вернутся на основную ОС? В инете ответа не нашел.

Comment: Вы начали операцию по смене пола и в какой-то момент поняли, что у вас недостаточно инструментов... Ни как. Несите в ремонтный центр, там люди с прямыми руками и отвественностью за принимаемые решения решат вашу проблему. Скорее всего вы форматнули диск и откатить на прошлую ОС у вас не получиться.

Comment: Я просто даун и не заметил красный крестик. Уже все восстановил